# Resolving Depedency Injection in ASP.NET Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have three Repository classes, which are:

```
 1. ITechniqueRepository 
 2. ITechniqueItemRepository
 3. ITechniqueAssesstmentRepository
```

There is another Service class, which is:

```
ITechniqueService
```

In ITechniqueService constructor, I have the following code to resolve Dependency Injection.

```
private readonly ITechniqueRepository _techniqueRepository;
private readonly ITechniqueItemRepository _techniqueItemRepository;
private readonly ITechniqueAssesstmentRepository _techniqueAssesstmentRepository;

    public TechniqueService(            
        ITechniqueRepository techniqueRepository,
        ITechniqueItemRepository techniqueItemRepository,
        ITechniqueAssesstmentRepository techniqueAssesstmentRepository
      ) : base(unitOfWork, settings, logger)
    {
        _techniqueRepository = techniqueRepository;
        _techniqueItemRepository = techniqueItemRepository;
        _techniqueAssesstmentRepository = techniqueAssesstmentRepository;
    }
```

In my controller constructor, I have the following code to resolve the dependency.

```
private readonly ITechniqueService _techniqueService;
    public TechniqueController(
        ITechniqueService techniqueService
        )
    {
        _techniqueService = techniqueService;
    }
```

And in my Startup class, I have the bellow code:

```
services.AddScoped<ITechniqueRepository, TechniqueRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITechniqueItemRepository, TechniqueItemRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITechniqueAssessmentRepository, TechniqueAssessmentRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITechniqueService, TechniqueService>();
```

The problem is when I execute my service, I get the below exception as response result.

> {
>
> "StatusCode": 3,
>
> "Message": "Unable to resolve service for type 'Data.Repositories.ITechniqueAssesstmentRepository' while attempting to activate
>   'Services.TechniqueService'.",
>
> "MessageDetail": "at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, ISet`1 callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor, Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2
>   dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean
>   isDefaultParameterRequired)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   IServiceProvider , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__23.MoveNext()",
>       "Errors": {} }

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: That should work fine, but where do you get the parameters passed to the `TechniqueService` base class? (unitOfWork, settings, logger)...

Comment: Yes, I have made an BaseService Class. from there the parameters are passed.

Comment: `base` is used to pass parameters _into_ the base class, not the other way around. You'd have to get references to those three things in `TechniqueService`. Dependency injection won't resolve anything in the base class constructor.

Comment: I have the code in startup class for solving the dependency in the base class. This approach is working fine for my other controller but it does not work in TechniqueController.

Comment: I'm not following you, but in any case, the error means it can't create `TechniqueAssesstmentRepository`, so what does that constructor look like?